# Properties of the field of values of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is known that the **field of values**, also known as **numerical range**, of a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ is a convex set whose boundary is an ellipse in $\Bbb C$.

$$F(A) := \left\{ x^\ast A x : x^\ast x = 1, x \in \Bbb C^2 \right\}$$

On the other hand, for two real matrices $A$ and $B$, it is known that $F(A + B)$ is a proper subset of $F(A) + F(B)$. Now, as an example, let's take

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad B = \begin{bmatrix}0&2\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

and plot $F(A), F(B)$ and $F(A+B)$ as follows

[image]

Is $F(A+B)$ a *proper* subset of $F(A)+F(B)$ in this figure? How can I verify that? What is "proper" here?

Comment: 1) I dont think you generally can say "proper subset", it could be equality (take one of the matrices as the zero matrix).  2)  Your figure for $F(A)$ cannot be correct, it is not a line, it is an ellipse.  3) what you have drawn seems to be $F(A+B)$, which is (very) diferentb from $F(A)+F(B)$.  Try again! last: $F(A)+F(B)$ is the "sum of sets", all elements have form $a+b$ where $a\in A, b\in B$.

Comment: Pavel Jiranek: Will correct above!  (Wanted to!  But seems I cannot edit the comment now! why?)

Comment: I used this http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/78B/jresv78Bn3p105_A1b.pdf
to plot $F(A)$. so for $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&2 \end{bmatrix}$  the imaginary parts are zero so it is only a line not an ellipse. The left yellow circle is $F(B)$ and the right yellow ellipse is $F(A+B)$ which has an overlap with $F(A)$.

Comment: here is also a MATLAB code for plotting the field of values for any matrix: https://www.math.iupui.edu/~ccowen/Downloads/33NumRange.html

Comment: @Arry $F(A)$ is a line because $A$ is $2\times 2$ and normal (Hermitian).

Comment: So if $F(A), F(B)$ and $F(A+B)$ are plotted correctly, then, it does not show that $F(A+B)$ is a subset of $F(A)+F(B)$ which is against the theorem?!

Comment: @Arry I don't know what do you mean. Do you want to disprove that $F(A+B)\subset F(A)+F(B)$ by an example? I'm afraid you can't since this is true for any $A$ and $B$ (real/complex). The only thing which is generally false in the statement of your question is that $F(A+B)$ is a proper subset of $F(A)+F(B)$ as noted in the first comment.

Comment: @pavel Jiranek, what I am trying to do is to confirm that $F(A+B)\subset F(A)+F(B)$ through this example which is plotted. BUT, I dont know if this plot confirms that $F(A+B)\subset F(A)+F(B)$ or not?

Comment: You should just plot $F(A) + F(B)$ and see that this is a much larger set than $F(A+B).$ In general, it's not easy to manually plot $X+Y$ given plots of $X$ and $Y$ separately.

Answer (score 0):

It is referring to [this sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset). The set of all possible sums between elements of $A$ and elements of $B$.